# Unable to Set/Select Date on JavaObject through UFT/QTP

Tags: java, datetime, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to set date on a Java Application. below is the image

[image]

1. The part in red is as :

   `JavaDialog("tagname:=DialogM").JavaList("index:=2")`
2. The part in Green is as :
   `JavaDialog("tagname:=DialogM").JavaObject("tagname:=JCalendarField\$DayList", "Index:=0")`

I've tried rather vainfully to set date here. I tried using "select", "click" with 1 and 2 and it didn't work. 
Also tried use SendKeys method (Just in case) didn't work either.
I'm out of ideas on what i would do to achieve this. Appreciate any help here

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you have a generic [JavaObject](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Java/JAVAPACKAGELib~JavaObject.html) instead of a [JavaCalendar](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Java/JAVAPACKAGELib~JavaCalendar.html) object. So, you won't benefit of JavaCalendar specific methods like "SetDate" which will select a specific date.

Have you tried to do a record and see the UFT's output?

Comment: exactly, and that is why i wanted to ask and see if there is any way if someone else might have come across.

- i did recording - it just clicks on coordinates. not much help with recording as well.