# How to set a date in monthcalendar using QTP for windows UI?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

This is for windows UI automation. I am having a month calendar object in my .net windows application and it does not have any field to input the date directly. The dates within the month are not getting recognized by Object Spy. I want to select a random date which will be getting passed via code in UFT. The calendar object's class type is `WindowsForms10.SysMonthCal32.app.0.13965fa_r30_ad1`

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using other add ins ?. Try opening the Application with UFT Tool and then use Spy or try using a record method see what does it give

Comment: Only the month window object is getting identified and not the dates. Tried recording and clicked on the dates, only clicks on co-ordinates are getting captured.

Comment: Can you please post your code here - ( the recorded one) or atleast the calender object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had same issues in a Java application : - check here [Unable to Set/Select Date on JavaObject through UFT/QTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325964/unable-to-set-select-date-on-javaobject-through-uft-qtp)

Assuming that you have the necessary addin installed/Selected. Try to check what sort of methods are available with the calender object. Such situation is a deadlock. The only way you can get around is

1. if the calender object has tab order i.e. you can select the dates through [TAB] or Arrow keys. Then you can use the Sendkeys Method
2. The last option is to involve the development team and ask them to change/edit the object such that UFT can identify it.

for me, we discarded the date functionality until the developer fixed the object.

Comment: I am in this situation where you were before. Trying for alternate workarounds and I already thought about your first suggestion before. It is responsive to arrow keys. No chance of changing the object.

Comment: Well, incase you stumble upon some solution other than this - Please do share it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this SetDate method of the object with class type "SysMonthCal32"

```
Window("regexpwndclass:=ClockFlyoutWindow").Wincalendar("Nativeclass:=SysMonthCal32").SetDate "31-Mar-2018"
```